# I am trying to delete a node from xml file Wp8

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8

Hi I am trying to delete a element from xml file using ISO storage ,the nodes gets deleted but the xml is deformed.

the code is :

```
public void deleteFromXML(string appName)
{

    using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var stream = isoStorage.OpenFile("ISOconfig.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(stream);
            xml.Descendants("ContainerApp")
                    .Where(x => x.Element("AppName").Value.Equals(appName))
                    .Remove();
            // stream.Position = 0;
            // xml.Save(stream);
            stream.Close();
            // Save To ISOconfig.xml File oeration not permited on IsolatedStorageFileStream

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream newStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ISOconfig.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, isoStorage))
            {
                xml.Save(newStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changes made is after the linq query closed the stream and saved it as:

stream.Close();
                    // Save To ISOconfig.xml File
                  using (IsolatedStorageFileStream newStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ISOconfig.xml", FileMode.Create, isoStorage))
                  {
                      xml.Save(newStream);
                  }

Comment: If you need to add context/code, please edit your question, do not post it as an answer.